# ndk - Experimental Gradle - How to add local LDLibs?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-plugin

My project has some prebuilt libraries and jni sources. Building them with the following Android.mk works fine.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := arcade

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := torchdemo.cpp torchandroid.cpp android_fopen.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/prebuilts -lluaT - lluajit -lTH  -lTHNN  -ltorch -lnnx -limage -ltorchandroid 


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`
```

This is my build.gradle

```
model {

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        ndk {
            moduleName "arcade"
            ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])

        }

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }


    }

    android.sources {

        main {
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs 'src/main/libs'
                }
            }
        }

        main {
            jni {
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "src/main/jni/include"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Building with gradle results in linker errors with undefined references as gradle is not adding the prebuilt libraries.How to add the ldlibs flag to local prebuilt libraries in gradle?.